# MySQL Syntax error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I tried running the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO VOUCHER (VOUCHER_NUMBER, BOOK_ID, DENOMINATION)
SELECT (a.number, b.ID, b.DENOMINATION) 
FROM temp_cheques a, BOOK b
WHERE a.number BETWEEN b.START_NUMBER AND b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1;
```

which, as I understand it, should insert into VOUCHER each record from temp_cheques with the ID and DENOMINATION fields corresponding to entries in the BOOK table (temp_cheques comes from a database backup, which I'm trying to recreate in a different format). However, when I run it, I get an error:

```
Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
SQLState:  21000
ErrorCode: 1241
```

I'm running this in SQuirrel and have not had issues with any other queries. Is there something wrong with the syntax of my query?

EDIT:

The structure of BOOK is:

```
ID  int(11)
START_NUMBER    int(11)
UNITS   int(11)
DENOMINATION    double(5,2)
```

The structure of temp_cheques is:

```
ID  int(11)
number  varchar(20)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the parenthesis in your SELECT clause?

Comment: Yes, and I get: Error: The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: I edited the fields so they are all int(11) and that did not affect the error

Comment: I dont know much of mysql. But does the query engine register schema changes? or it has to be restarted for it to read the modified schema?

Comment: This is correct. Assuming you have many rows in both BOOK and temp_cheques, you're trying to query all rows from both tables and make a cross-reference. Set SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 before running this statement.

Comment: ...And note that it'll probably take a while.

Comment: Thanks lc, post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct. I did that, and removed the parentheses in the select, and it worked.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. Fixing database schemas can be a real pain, can't it?

Comment: Check this out:
http://sourcecodeissues.blogspot.com/2011/09/1241-operand-should-contain-1-columns.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis from the SELECT clause. From [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263.aspx), the correct syntax for an INSERT statement using a SELECT clause is the following.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable  (PriKey, Description)
       SELECT ForeignKey, Description
       FROM SomeView
```

---

The error you're getting, "The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay.", is actually correct, assuming you have many rows in both BOOK and temp_cheques.  You are trying to query all rows from both tables and make a cross-reference, resulting in an m*n size query. SQL Server is trying to warn you of this, before performing a potentially long operation.

Set `SQL_BIG_SELECTS` = 1 before running this statement, and try again. It should work, but note that this operation may take a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Does B contain the UNITS column?

What is the table structure for temp_cheques and Book?

EDIT: As I said in comments, all the columns should be numeric when doing +/- and when comparing.
 Does the following simple SELECT work?

`SELECT b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1 FROM Books B`

Comment: Yes to the first question. and I've provided the relevant portions of the structure.

Comment: Can Between be applied to varchar? Also, what does b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1 mean to a varchar column? I think you should cast it to numeric column and apply "-1" to it.

Comment: I would suggest modifying the title to have error message. That might help people searching for it (rather than generic mysql error thing)

Comment: I updated that to int(11) like the other field, but I get the same error.

Comment: try using it in a select. SELECT b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1 FROM Books B - does this statement work?

Comment: If that works, try putting the computing in a WHERE clause.
e.g. SELECT b.ID, b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1 FROM Books B WHERE b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1 > 10000

I am doubting that mysql doesn't allow computed columns in a where clause.

Comment: Post your findings in a separate comment & try explaining as to how did you fix it. It will help others.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a MySQL instance handy, but my first guess is the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE a.number BETWEEN b.START_NUMBER AND b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1;
```

I imagine that the MySQL parser may be interpreting that as:

```
WHERE number
(BETWEEN start_number AND start_number) + units - 1
```

Try wrapping everything in parentheses, ie:

```
WHERE a.number BETWEEN b.START_NUMBER AND (b.START_NUMBER + b.UNITS - 1);
```

Comment: It couldn't be; there's no other place for the "+b.UNITS-1" to go. It would either go in the BETWEEN statement, or throw an invalid token error.

Comment: Unless it did parse it correctly (as far as the between statement goes) and my error is something different. All I know is that with or without the parentheses, I get the same error.

Comment: It couldn't be = this couldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The final version of the query is as follows:

```
Set SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;
INSERT INTO VOUCHER (VOUCHER_NUMBER, BOOK_ID, DENOMINATION)
SELECT a.number, b.ID, b.DENOMINATION
FROM temp_cheques a, BOOK b
WHERE a.number BETWEEN b.START_NUMBER AND (b.START_NUMBER+b.UNITS-1);
```

The parsing of the BETWEEN statement required parentheses, the SELECT did not, and because of the size of the two tables (215000 records in temp_cheques, 8000 in BOOK) I was breaking a limit on the select size, requiring me to set SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1.

Comment: Yeah, you were trying to do a cross reference on 1.7 billion combinations. Nothing wrong with it, of course, just with that many comparisons, it wanted to make sure you REALLY wanted to do it.

Comment: at least I won't have to do this again... and it only took about 5 seconds to run.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error when using Spring Repositories.

My repository contained a method like:

```
List<SomeEntity> findAllBySomeId(List<String> ids);
```

This is working fine when running integration tests against an in-memory database (h2). However against a stand alone database like MySql is was failing with the same error.

I've solved it by changing the method interface to:

```
List<someEntity findBySomeIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

Note: there is no difference between `find` and `findAll`. As described here:  [Spring Data JPA difference between findBy / findAllBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37321365/1546042)