# MySQL INSERT on duplicate key UPDATE with SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, on-duplicate-key

I have a query like the following

```
INSERT INTO connections (`c_id`,`in`,`out`,`ip`,`userID`) 
VALUES ( 
    ( 
        SELECT c_id 
        FROM connections 
        WHERE (a bunch of conditions) 
        ORDER BY c_id DESC LIMIT 1 

    ),
    '1373799802',
    0,
    INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),
    4

) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `out` = 1
```

Which throws the following error

> 1093 - You can't specify target table 'connections' for update in FROM clause

Obviously I can't have a SELECT clause within the `insert into on duplicate update` syntax, but I'd really rather do that instead of have 2 queries running. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [**How to INSERT INTO...SELECT with ON DUPLICATE KEY**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14701250/342740)

Comment: @prix I don't see how this can apply to my issue, I only have 1 table

Comment: You don't need 2 tables however your query is wrong and you can see from the example there what is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to INSERT INTO...SELECT with ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700664/how-to-insert-into-select-with-on-duplicate-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
INSERT INTO connections (`c_id`,`in`,`out`,`ip`,`userID`) 
VALUES ( 
    ( 
SELECT p.c_id 
        FROM (select * from connections) p 
        WHERE (a bunch of conditions) 
        ORDER BY p.c_id DESC LIMIT 1 

    ),
    '1373799802',
    0,
    INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),
    4

) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `out` = 1
```

This issue seems due to a bug in mysql version 4.1.7 which states that

```
you can't update the same table which you use in the SELECT part
```

see [Here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6980)

Not sure if this is the same version you are using as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    INSERT INTO connections (`c_id`,`in`,`out`,`ip`,`userID`) 
    SELECT c_id ,'1373799802', 0, INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),4
    FROM connections 
    WHERE (a bunch of conditions) 
    ORDER BY c_id DESC LIMIT 1 

    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `out` = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code inside your query:

```
SELECT c_id 
FROM connections 
WHERE (a bunch of conditions) 
ORDER BY c_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

actually results in a table and not a single value. For a successful attempt, try this:

```
INSERT INTO connections (`c_id`,`in`,`out`,`ip`,`userID`) 
    SELECT  c_id,
            '1373799802',
            0,
            INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),
            4
    FROM connections 
    WHERE (a bunch of conditions) 
    ORDER BY c_id DESC LIMIT 1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE `out` = 1
```

Comment: How come does the first query result in a table when I only select a single column and a limit of 1 result? Also can you please explain why I must have all values as a result set from a select clause instead of how I've written it?

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to add a new row if the conditions are not met :/