# Operand should contain 1 column(s)??? IT DOES but still error. Is this a bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, contain, operand, mysql-error-1241

I'm having a verry strange problem. I am certain I have done nothing wrong in this line of code:

```
INSERT INTO 
 oc_address     
  (`cust_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `address_1`, `city`, `postcode`, `country_id`)
SELECT          
  (`cust_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`, `city`, `postalcode`, `country`)
FROM    old_customer;
```

Still I get the message "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Does anybony see something I don't see? I was thinking it may be caused by the _1 at address_1. But why would that be...
I hope there is another explanation

Comment: I would try removing the () from the select statement

Comment: @HLGEM YES it did work! What a stupid stupid mistake of me. Thanks you verry much

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456644/mysql-syntax-error-message-operand-should-contain-1-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `( )` around the columns on `SELECT` ststement,

```
INSERT  INTO oc_address (cust_id, firstname, lastname, address_1, city, postcode, country_id)
SELECT cust_id, first_name, last_name, address, city, postalcode, country
FROM    old_customer;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*two statements included*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eef87/1)

Comment: I would have guessed that too. @RamiNagiebMourshedy could you try remove `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `'` symbols for your column names and the `()` in your `SELECT`.

```
  INSERT INTO 
  oc_address     
  (cust_id, firstname, lastname, address_1, city, postcode,country_id)
  SELECT          
  cust_id, first_name, last_name, address, city, postalcode, country
  FROM    old_customer;
```

Comment: -1 no comments ? what is wrong  with my answer?

Comment: nevermind them, i have also `2` downvotes on my answer. hehe your answer is also correct.