# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in java

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

```
String  sql = "SELECT (Employee_name, Password) FROM employee WHERE (Employee_name = '"+name+"'  AND Password = '"+password+"')";
```

and getting the following exception in JSP
java.sql.sqlexception insert operand should contain 1 column(s)

Please help.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from around your `SELECT` list.

Comment: Also remember to sanitize the values of name and password if they are given as input by the user. Otherwise it can leave you vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks alot 4 ur reply:)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167933/1546042 for a spring repository related issue & solution.

Answer (score 5):

Correct way is

```
String  sql = "SELECT Employee_name, Password FROM employee WHERE Employee_name = '"+name+"'  AND Password = '"+password+"'";
```

You can keep `()` for where clause but not in select list.
This is what happens in your case

```
mysql> select (firstname,email) from users limit 1 ;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove brackets and it will work.

```
String  sql = "SELECT Employee_name, Password 
           FROM employee WHERE Employee_name = '"+name+"'  
                      AND Password = '"+password+"'";
```

Generally we are using brackets when we need to add Nested Queries and for combining conditions. if you add brackets for column names Mysql identified it as a single column. Thats why the error comes out as its is.

Answer (score 1):

Your query must be this:

```
String  sql = "SELECT Employee_name, Password 
                  FROM employee 
                   WHERE (Employee_name = '"+name+"'  
                     AND Password = '"+password+"')";
```