# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql

```
select a.NAME_
    ,b.EXECUTION_ID_
    ,b.CREATE_TIME_
    ,a.TEXT_ 
from ACT_RU_VARIABLE a 
    inner join ACT_RU_TASK b on a.EXECUTION_ID_=b.EXECUTION_ID_ 
where a.NAME_= 'ticketId' 
    and b.CREATE_TIME_ in (select created_date 
                               ,priority 
                           from help_desk_ticket) ;
```

Comment: You could have googled this, and your title has lost part of the error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Syntax error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456644/mysql-syntax-error-message-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Answer (score 1):

it expects a single row from your subquery. remove `priority` from there:

```
select a.NAME_, b.EXECUTION_ID_, b.CREATE_TIME_, a.TEXT_ 
from ACT_RU_VARIABLE a 
inner join ACT_RU_TASK b on a.EXECUTION_ID_=b.EXECUTION_ID_ 
where 
    a.NAME_= 'ticketId' 
    and b.CREATE_TIME_ in (select created_date from help_desk_ticket)
```