# Move records with unique field into 2nd table

Tags: mysql, select, unique

I have 2 tables. `table_a` is current data, `table_b` has updated data. The 1st thing I need to do is move all new records, i.e., move the records from `table_a` to `table_b` that have a value in a primary index field (`primaryField`) not found in `table_a`.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,etc...)
VALUES (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,etc...)
FROM table_a
WHERE table_a.primaryField NOT IN (SELECT table_b.primaryField)
```

This approach doesn't work. How do you select only the rows in a table that have values for a specific field not found in the matching field of a 2nd table?

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` `table_a` to `table_b` and then insert only those records in `table_a` which do not match anything in `table_b`.

```
INSERT INTO table_b (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.primaryField = b.primaryField
WHERE b.primaryField IS NULL
```

Comment: Tim - I tried this and got an error on line 3. I checked typos and syntax and didn't find an error.

Comment: Your original syntax was off.  Try using `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM`.

Comment: Tim - you were correct, I missed the change from VALUES to SELECT. Having corrected that, I get an error that col1 in the SELECT statement is ambiguous. I don't see why since it's specified as FROM table_a. If it's ambiguous because of the JOIN, how do I add a table reference in the SELECT line?

Comment: `col1` was ambiguous because apparently both `table_a` and `table_b` have such a column.  So MySQL could not figure out to which column you were referring.  I have corrected this by explicitly referring to `table_a`.

Comment: I've added the table reference to the select fields and  got rid of the ambiguity. The result now errs:  Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: Remove the parentheses from your `SELECT` clause, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456644/mysql-syntax-error-message-operand-should-contain-1-columns).

Comment: Thanks Tim - appreciate you staying with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT primaryField
From Table_a
WHERE primaryField NOT IN (SELECT primaryField FROM Table_b)
```

and you query can be

```
INSERT INTO table_b (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,etc...)
VALUES (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,etc...)
FROM table_a
WHERE table_a.primaryField NOT IN (SELECT primaryField FROM table_b.primaryField)
```

Comment: Abbas - I had tried the 2nd part as a query and it didn't work. I wasn't sure what to do with the first part. Was the 2nd part supposed to be a subquery?