# Spring Data JPA difference between findBy / findAllBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there any difference when using Spring Data JPA keywords between:

```
List<SomeEntity> findBySomeCondition();
```

and

```
List<SomeEntity> findAllBySomeCondition();
```

Answer (score 196, accepted):

No, there is no difference between them, they will execute exactly the same query, the `All` part is ignored by Spring Data when deriving the query from the method name. The only important bit is the `By` keyword, anything following it is treated as a field name (with the exception of other keywords like `OrderBy` which incidentially can lead to some strange looking method names like `findAllByOrderByIdAsc`).

This means something like this is perfectly valid:

```
List<SomeEntity> findAnythingYouWantToPutHereBySomeCondition();
```

And will execute exactly the same SQL query as:

```
List<SomeEntity> findBySomeCondition();
```

or

```
List<SomeEntity> findAllBySomeCondition();
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.3.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) for the 2.3.6 release of Spring Data discusses this feature:

> Any text between `find` (or other introducing keywords) and `By` is considered to be descriptive unless using one of the result-limiting keywords such as a `Distinct` to set a distinct flag on the query to be created or `Top`/`First` to limit query results.

The purpose of feature was explained in a [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/20/a-preview-on-spring-data-kay#improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods) about the then-upcoming 2.0 release of Spring Data:

> Spring Data’s method parsing uses prefix keywords like `find`, `exists`, `count`, and `delete` and a terminating `By` keyword. Everything you put in between `find` and `By` makes your method name more expressive and does not affect query derivation.

Comment: Thanks for specifying the OrderBy definition , showing that the By is necessary before the OrderBy

Comment: is there anywhere a FULL documentation about query creation (including modifying)? I can find only fragments (e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation - no word about ..all.., remove..)

Comment: Then why is it even there?

Comment: I can't find the prefix naming behavior defined in the docs either, but there is one thing that _will_ change the behavior when included in the prefix: the term "Distinct", e.g. "`findDistinctBySomeCondition()`: [4.4.2. Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Issue [DATACMNS-1833](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1833) now exists in Spring's issue tracker requesting better documentation of this feature.

Comment: This is now in the [2.3.6 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.3.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation): "Any text between find (or other introducing keywords) and By is considered to be descriptive unless using one of the result-limiting keywords such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to be created or Top/First to limit query results."

Comment: Although there is no technical difference, I think that a method that filters the result with "by" should not be named "findAll", because it just does not find ALL entries.

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate the difference lets look at the two functions:

```
1. Set<Policy> findAllByRoleIn(Iterable<Role> role);

2. Set<Policy> findByRoleIn(Iterable<Role> role);
```

The query generated by 1st function:

```
1.  select policy.id, policy.role from policy where (policy.role in (? , ? , ? , ?))
```

The query generated by 2nd function:

```
2. select policy.id, policy.role from policy where (policy.role in (? , ? , ? , ?))
```

**Conclusion**: Clearly, if we look at the queries generated by both functions. We can clearly see, there is no difference between the two function definitions, they execute exactly the same query.

Answer (score 0):

one difference is that with findAllBy Hibernate filters (@Filters from org.hibernate.annotations) are applied and so a different sql.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the difference between findallBy and findby, is that :
findAllBy returns a Collection but
findBy returns Optional.

so it's preferable to write List findAllBy instead of writing List findBy (but it will work also :p).
and to write Optional findBy instead of Optional findAllBy.

check this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Comment: No, findBy could return a list.

Answer (score -5):

findBy method is used if we want to find by name or some other criteria like    `findByFirstName(String firstName);`

findAll methods generally finds by providing specification

```
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);
```

Please see docs below for more clarity:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: No, that method which you are wrote is from JPASpecificationExecutor. I'm talking about just JpaRepository. I can create method findAllByFirstName(String firstName) and it will work similar to findByFirstName. In this question I'm trying to understand difference between them.