# search in crud using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to add **search** field in the crud project I used the method `findAllByNameAndLast(Name, Last);` but the method is not working also I don't know how to return a result to the `index.html`

project link is : [project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bfxkrtmpdp8gdb/NinoosCrude.zip?dl=0)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEmployee/{firstname}/{lastname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable("name") String Name, @PathVariable("last") String Last, ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Student> student = re.findAllByNameAndLast(Name,Last);
    modelMap.addAttribute("message", student);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: What does "the method is not working" mean? Do you get a compile error, or an exception when you run the program? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your controller method like below.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEmployee/{firstname}/{lastname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable("firstname") String Name, @PathVariable("lastname") String Last, ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Student> student = re.findByNameAndLast(Name,Last);
    modelMap.addAttribute("message", student);
    return "index";
}
```

and in jsp iterate this list using foreach loop like below :

```
<c:foreach items="message" var="item">
  <c:cout value="item.name"></c:out>
  <c:cout value="item.last"></c:out>
</c:foreach>
```

Use `findByNameAndLast` instead of `findAllByNameAndLast` as but this is not the reason behind failure of your code because jpa ignores `all` in `findAllByNameAndLast`

[Spring Data JPA difference between findBy / findAllBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253571/spring-data-jpa-difference-between-findby-findallby)