# How add where condition in fillAll method in spring boot using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot framework with hibernate. I want to show all data from database only certain conditions. Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `client_master` WHERE CLIENT_GROUP='S'
```

I want to get data which CLIENT_GROUP data has only S. I have used bellow cod for spring boot..

1. Model  I have used bellow code..

   ```
    @Entity
   @Table(name = "client_master")
   public class ClientMasterModel {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     @Column(name= "ID")
     private int ID;

     @Column(name= "NAME")
     private String name;

     //getter or setter
    }
   ```
2. My repository is bellow

   ```
     public interface Staff_Add_Repository extends JpaRepository<ClientMasterModel, Long> {

   }
   ```
3. In service, I have used bellow code..

   ```
     @Autowired
   Staff_Add_Repository add_Repository;


    public List<ClientMasterModel> findAll(){
      return add_Repository.findAll();
    }
   ```

   Above method returns all data. I want to get only specific data .
   How to do it? Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<ClientMasterModel> findByClientGroup(String clientGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a field named `clientGroup` in your `ClientMasterModel` you just need a correctly named method and possibly - if you wish - a default wrapper method in your repository as following:

```
public interface Staff_Add_Repository
            extends JpaRepository<ClientMasterModel, Long> {

    List<ClientMasterModel> findByClientGroup(String clientGroup);

    default List<ClientMasterModel> findWhereClientGroupIsS() {
        return findByClientGroup("S");
    }

}
```

Also the `findAllBy` is a synonym to `findBy`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37253571/6413377)