# Operand should contain 1 column(s) for multiple table query

Tags: php, mysql

Actually I am inserting two multiple table data into one table, I have written following query where I wanted to insert some fields from both table into the new table. I wrote the code for newly submitted form for my website but I wanted to update existing data in database.

Please have a look on below qyery. 
Please suggest.

below query is giving me an error:

"Operand should contain 1 column(s) "

```
            INSERT INTO am_intranet_hr_lead_document(doc_name,careers_submissions_key,hr_phase_key,response_id,date_added) 
            SELECT (am_career_submissions.resume,am_career_submissions.careers_submissions_key,am_intranet_hr_lead_response.hr_phase_key,am_intranet_hr_lead_response.response_id,am_career_submissions.add_dt) 
            FROM am_career_submissions, am_intranet_hr_lead_response 
            WHERE am_career_submissions.careers_submissions_key = am_intranet_hr_lead_response.careers_submissions_key
```

Thank You.

Comment: Similar kind of issue addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456644/mysql-syntax-error-message-operand-should-contain-1-columns).

Comment: Thanks Ravi, the link you suggested is helpful for me. This reloved my problem. I just removed paranthesis from that.

Comment: Don't use  bracket `(` , if you are seleting more than one columns from the table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do with inner join and limit
Like this

```
INSERT INTO am_intranet_hr_lead_document(doc_name,careers_submissions_key,hr_phase_key,response_id,date_added) 
           SELECT (am_career_submissions.resume,am_career_submissions.careers_submissions_key,am_intranet_hr_lead_response.hr_phase_key,am_intranet_hr_lead_response.response_id,am_career_submissions.add_dt) 
            FROM am_career_submissions, 
            join am_intranet_hr_lead_response 
            on am_career_submissions.careers_submissions_key = am_intranet_hr_lead_response.careers_submissions_key
            limit 1
```

Comment: Hi Bibhudatta, Thanks for the reply. But above query is giving me an arror like  1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT (am_career_submissions.resume,am_career_submissions.careers_submissions_k' at line 2

Comment: Okay i got it just remove the `value(`and `)` from the query.Try this query again.